# Apache Hive - Merging a single column from one table into another under a new name

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am working with two tables, both having an ID column with the same name, and I need to find a way to merge the id from one table into the other, under a new column name.  In addition, I need to keep all of the rows from the left table and just update the new column with the existing ID from the right table.  If there is not a corresponding ID in the right table, the value after merging the column in should be null.

```
Table 1

Houses
--------------------------------------
| ID |  Address                    
--------------------------------------
| 1  |  123 Main
| 2  |  234 Center
| 3  |  345 North Street

Table 2
Houses that are blue
--------------------------------------
| ID |  Address
--------------------------------------
| 2  |  234 Center



Resultant table:  
Houses
    
--------------------------------------
| ID |  Address          |  BlueHouseID
--------------------------------------
| 1  |  123 Main         |  NULL
| 2  |  234 Center       |  2
| 3  |  345 North        |  NULL
```

Thanks in advance for any help on setting this query up.  This will ultimately be going in an overwrite text file for later ingestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just `left join` :

```
select h.*, b.id as blue_house_id
from houses h
left join blue_houses b on b.id = h.id
```

Or maybe you want to match on the address rather than on the `id`:

```
select h.*, b.id as blue_house_id
from houses h
left join blue_houses b on b.address = h.address
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join`:

```
select h.*, hb.id as blue_id
from houses h left join
     houses_blue hb
     on h.id = hb.id
```